# Solve the equation $\left\lvert x - 1 \right\rvert=1-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is wrong in this solution:

> Solve the equation $\;\left\lvert x - 1 \right\rvert=1-x$.

$$x-1=1-x \implies 2x=2 \implies x=1$$

OR

$$-\left(x-1\right)=1-x \implies -x+1=1-x \implies 0=0$$

Comment: Its not finished. What are the solutions of the equation? I.e. for which $x$ is the equation true?

Comment: @vikram check your second equation again

Answer (score 1):

For real $y,|y|=+y$ if $y\ge0$  else $=-y$

So if $x-1\ge0\iff x\ge1,|x-1|=x-1$

Else i.e., for $x<1,|x-1|=-(x-1)=1-x$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

By definition $$|x-1|=\begin{cases}x-1\ \mbox{ for }\ x>1\\1-x\ \mbox{ for }\ x\leq1\end{cases}$$
such that $|x-1|=1-x$ for $x\leq1$.